# Get List<T> from List<T> that contains parameter matching in List<int>

Tags: c#

I have a List containing the Id property of some objects.
I have a List where I need a new List but only objects that has an Id matching in List.

How to do this with best performance?

Answer (score 2):

Using linq:

```
List<MyClass> results = mylist.FindAll(x => listOfIds.Contains(x.ID));
```

Or if `listOfIds` has many many records:

```
HashSet<int> hashedIds = new HashSet<int>(listOfIds);
List<MyClass> results = mylist.FindAll(x => hashedIds.Contains(x.ID));
```

Finding Ids in `HashSet<T>` is far more faster than `List<T>`

If you need to enumerate items one by one then:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> results = mylist.Where(x => listOfIds.Contains(x.ID));
foreach(MyClass item in results)
{
   // do your work
}
```